# CI CD components information neeeded

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We have a requirement of implementation of CI CD for the below PAAS components via VSTS Build -release pipelines:

1)Azure automation

2)Azure Data Warehouse

3)ADF v1

4)ADF v2

5)Key vault

6)Azure Storage

Any document pertaining to any of the above components would be very helpful.
I am looking for documentation specific to the build & release pipelines.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not really a good idea to post such a broad question like this. But have you tried the official documentations?

1. [Azure Devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/index?view=azure-devops)
2. [azure pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/index?view=azure-devops)
3. [Azure KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/)
4. [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction)
5. [Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-overview-what-is)
6. [Azure Active Directory V.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-overview)
7. [Azure Active Directory V.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview)

Also try out the chat service for azure devops at [aka.ms/devchat](http://aka.ms/devchat). They usually are helpful. :)